# Prove that $(z_n)_n$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $(w_nz_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a null sequence (a sequence tending to $0$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$, $(z_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $(w_n)_{n\geq 1}$(a null sequence) be sequences.

Prove that $(z_n)_n$ is bounded  $\Rightarrow$ $(w_nz_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a null sequence (a sequence tending to $0$)

Is that even a correct statement? I don't see a bounded sequence multiplied with any sequence would be a null sequence...

Can you enlighten me? Any ideas, impulses would help!

Comment: At a guess, the question might be missing the crucial premise that $w_n$ is a null sequence. If this is also the case, then $w_n z_n \to 0$ as required.

Comment: sorry, $w_n$ is a null sequence.

Comment: Hint: apply squeeze theorem to $|w_n z_n|$ to show it tends to $0$.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. So if there are two sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\leq (w_nz_n)_{n\geq 1} \leq (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, I have to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=wz$ How do I do that?

Comment: You'll need to apply it to $|w_n z_n|$, not $w_n z_n$, as the latter is a complex number, and it doesn't make sense to say it's greater than or less than another complex number. The sequence $|w_n z_n|$ is always bounded below by $0$, so just show it's bounded above by a null-convergent (real) sequence. Once you've shown this, you'll need to argue why this implies $w_n z_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_n$ is bounded, some $r>0$ exists with $|z_n|\le r$ for all $n$. For $\epsilon>0$, fix $N\in\Bbb N$ so $\forall n\in\Bbb N(n\ge N\implies |w_n|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{r})$ (we can do this because $(w_n)_{n\ge1}$ is null), so that $\forall n\in\Bbb N(n\ge N\implies |w_n z_n|\lt\epsilon)$. Since we can do this for any $\epsilon>0$, $(w_nz_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a null sequence.

Answer (score 0):

No, the statement is *not* correct. A similar but correct statement would be: if $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence and if $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a null sequence, then the sequence $(w_nz_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a null sequence.

Comment: Isn't that like proving that $x\cdot 0=0$?

Comment: No. It's more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

No ! Simply consider, $z_n :=1 , \forall n \in \Bbb N$ and $w_n:=1+ \frac{1}{n}$ , then $z_n w_n = 1+ \frac{1}{n} \to 1 \ne 0$  (as $n \to \infty$)

Here all we are using is that $\{w_n\} \subset \Bbb C$ is eventually bounded away from 0 i.e. if  given $\epsilon > 0$ , $\exists r \in \Bbb N$ such that $|w_n| > \epsilon , \forall n \ge r$  .

If in addition you assume that , $w_n \to 0 $ as $ n \to +\infty$ then by using the Bound on $\{z_n\}$ you should be able to get that $z_n w_n \to 0$